# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6 getting this error while upadating my fields

Tags: jsp

I am getting a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, can you help me find out why.

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>        
    <% String x=session.getAttribute("userid").toString();
    try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:college");
    //i have other fields which i dont want ot update they are
    //enrollment,name,password,father,dob,course,address,mobile,email(all
    //are in series of database) 
    PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("update Student set 
    Father=?,Address=?,Mobile=?,Email=? where SID='"+x+"' ");
    pst.setString(4,request.getParameter("t1"));
    pst.setString(7,request.getParameter("t2"));
    pst.setString(8,request.getParameter("t3"));
    pst.setString(10,request.getParameter("t4")); 
    int y=pst.executeUpdate();
    if(y>0)
    {
    out.println("Record Updated Successfully");    
    %>
    <%@include file="Student.jsp" %> <%    } else
    out.println("Updation unsuccessfull");
    }catch(Exception ee) {
    out.print(ee);%>
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pst.setString(1,request.getParameter("t1"));` ?? Indexes in `setXXXX()` should start with `1` !!!

Comment: What is inside that included JSP ?

Answer (score 0):

Where do these index values come from?:

```
pst.setString(4,request.getParameter("t1"));
pst.setString(7,request.getParameter("t2"));
pst.setString(8,request.getParameter("t3"));
pst.setString(10,request.getParameter("t4"));
```

You have only 4 substitution tokens.  I think you want:

```
pst.setString(1,request.getParameter("t1"));
pst.setString(2,request.getParameter("t2"));
pst.setString(3,request.getParameter("t3"));
pst.setString(4,request.getParameter("t4"));
```

Comment: these values t1 t2,t3,t4 comes form the textfield which i want to update

Comment: i got answer for my porbleum of updation     PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("update Student set Father='"+f+"' , Address='"+address+"' , Mobile='"+mob+"' , Email='"+email+"' where SID='"+x+"' ");

int y=pst.executeUpdate();
 if(y>0)
        {
          out.println("Record Updated Successfully");    
         
%>